# Foreign key field is not getting updated after save method in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entity class. One is Admin which contains id, username and password.
Other is Address class which contains id, country, state, address and f_id(which references to id of Admin table).
I have a service class which accepts the request data and creates Admin instance and updates all the values to it. But when I save the Admin instance using save() method, I can see data getting updated in both Admin and Address table but the problem is f_id field in Address table is not updated with its Admin id which is referenced to it. It is null.
[image]

Admin.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "admin")
public class Admin {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "admin", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;

    public Admin(UUID id, String username, String password, Address address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Admin() {

    }
....Setters and getters
```

Address.Java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Data
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    private String address;

    private String country;

    private String state;

   @JoinColumn(name = "f_id")
   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Admin admin;


}
```

AdminService.java()

```
@Service
public class AdminService {

    @Autowired
    AdminRepo adminRepo;

    @Autowired
    AddressRepo addressRepo;

    public Admin saveAdminDetails(AdminSaveRequest requestDto){
        Admin admin = new Admin();
        Address address = new Address();
        admin.setUsername(requestDto.getUserName());
        admin.setPassword(requestDto.getPassword());
        address.setAddress(requestDto.getAddress().getAddress());
        address.setCountry(requestDto.getAddress().getCountry());
        address.setState(requestDto.getAddress().getState());
        admin.setAddress(address);
        System.out.println(admin);
        Admin admin1 =  adminRepo.save(admin);
        System.out.println(admin1.toString());
        return admin1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the relationship is bi-directional. You need to set both ends. Like this:

```
admin.setAddress(address);
address.setAdmin(admin);
Admin admin1 =  adminRepo.save(admin);
```

Comment: when I do this, getting this below error, -> 
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
 at com.becoder.model.admin.Admin.toString(Admin.java:67) ~[classes/:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951) ~[na:na]
 at com.becoder.model.admin.Address.toString(Address.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2951) ~[na:na]

Comment: This is because of circular calling of toString() methods generated by Lombok. Add ToString.Exclude annotation to the relationship fields. And add JsonIgnore annotation to them to avoid stackoverflow on JSON serialization.

Comment: it worked. Thanks. I have one more problem.
`
public List<Admin> getAllAdminDetails(){
        return adminRepo.findAll();
    }
`
When i call this method, I get array of saved admin details but address field is coming as null. Any suggestion why ?
[
{
        "id": "3f3f05da-9215-4855-a7d6-e0ac3dfc95a1",
        "username": "pachu",
        "password": "asd",
        "address": null
    }
]

Comment: This should work either. Are you sure that an address associated to this particular admin exists? Check in the database: select * from address where f_id = '3f3f05da-9215-4855-a7d6-e0ac3dfc95a1';